# How to map home url (/) to Struts 2 REST Action

Tags: url, rest, struts2, mapping, action

I am developing a web application using Struts 2 and REST plugin. I already developed all the basic functionality of the application in REST style: myapp.org/login, myapp.org/register, myapp.org/profile, etc. Now I have to make the home page and get everything together. My question is: Is there any way to map the home (base) URL of the application to any Action class in REST style. I mean for example myapp.org to map to Home action class, insted of myapp.org/home to map to the Home action class?
Thank you in advance.
Best regards, 
Rashid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the welcome file in web.xml

```
<web-app /*stuff*/ >    
/*stuff*/
    <welcome-file-list>
       <welcome-file>home.action</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: That's interesting. Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I will be able to try it out tonight. I will let you know if it worked.